# Google Drive API Initialization and First Time Use Issue

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have an Android application I am writing that uses the Google Drive API. I am using the Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER to have a private location to put my application data, if the user chooses to sync the app with their Google drive. For the most part everything works fine and I can sync contents to the Google drive. However, I am having major difficulties on the initialization front. First of all, I can recognize when the users has not used the Google drive and launch the sign in activity. Here is how I build my google sign in client. I don't actually think I need the .requestEmail() and .requestProfile() but it is there for now.

```
    private GoogleSignInClient buildGoogleSignInClient(AppCompatActivity activity) {
    GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
            new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .requestProfile()
                    .build();
    return GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity, signInOptions);
}
```

To recognize that the user has not signed into to Google Drive or used the Drive with the app I have the following code.

```
   private void initGoogleClient() {
       mGoogleSignInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity());
       if (mGoogleSignInAccount == null) {
          launchSigninActivity(getActivity());
       } else {
          mDriveResourceClient = Drive.getDriveResourceClient(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mGoogleSignInAccount);
        //.... doing stuff here that works fine
    }
}
```

To launch the sign in activity I have the following code.

```
    private void launchSigninActivity(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        mGoogleSignInClient = buildGoogleSignInClient(activity);
        Intent signinIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        activity.startActivityForResult(signinIntent, SIGNIN_INTENT_CODE);
   }
```

Now the sign in activity gets launched just fine and users can sign in to their Google account. However, any time the Google UI is presented to sign in the user, the error code, code=8 INTERNAL_ERROR is thrown. If the user has previously signed into their drive account before using my app, the error code 8  is not thrown.

```
public void handleSignIn(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
    try {
        mGoogleSignInAccount = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
        mDriveResourceClient = Drive.getDriveResourceClient(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mGoogleSignInAccount);
        //... other App specific stuff
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "************* signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

(onActivityResults() in my activity calls the code above) The getActivity() method just returns the activity that handled the onActivityResults().

The second issue I have noticed is that there are some timing issues when using the GoogleResourceClient on first time use with my app. The first few times I try to read the drive, it seems to be empty, but at some point the remote files show up. I have not characterized how long it takes before reads find files but it seems that the drive API is returning before any calls to the remote drive on initial/first time app use calls.

These issues only happen on first time use of the Android app. All subsequent launches of the app run smooth. Does anyone have any ideas about these issues?

Comment: I have found others with this issue. If you are having this issue please go to the google issues and star the issue to get some focus by google. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760894

Answer (score 0):

Google had deprecated this library. Move the the Google Drive REST API.

Answer (score 0):

People still looking for help on Google Drive API related API help for Android, Google has prepared a sample app to showcase the new V3 API (and you need to migrate) here:

https://github.com/googleworkspace/android-samples/tree/master/drive/deprecation

It was a great help for me.

Migration Notice
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/migrate-to-v3

@musterjunk - you need requestEmail() as Drive API will not work without that